# Trigger a second query from LiveData and merge results (Firestore)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have two collections: Users and Books.  I need to get the results of both of them whether Users OR Books is updated and then merge the results together into a LinkedHashMap to use as a listView menu.

I thought a MediatorLiveData would be the way to go, but if I put the query of Users and the Query of Books in then I get null from one of the two LiveData objects because only one or the other fires.  I thought maybe if one of them fires, then perhaps I have a query run inside each addSource() in the MediatorLiveData, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

My post regarding the MediatorLiveData is here:
[Using MediatorLiveData to merge to LiveData (Firestore) QuerySnapshot streams is producing weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495476/using-mediatorlivedata-to-merge-to-livedata-firestore-querysnapshot-streams-is)

My two queries and LiveData objects are as follows:

```
//getUsers query using FirebaseQueryLiveData class
private Query getUsersQuery() {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    adminID = mAuth.getUid();
    query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("admins")
            .document(adminID)
            .collection("users")
    return query;
}

private FirebaseQueryLiveData usersLiveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(getUsersQuery());


//getBooks query using FirebaseQueryLiveData class
private Query getBooksQuery () {
    FirebaseGroupID firebaseGroupID = new FirebaseGroupID(getApplication());
    groupID = firebaseGroupID.getGroupID();
    query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("books")
            .whereEqualTo("groupID", groupID)      
    return query;
}

private FirebaseQueryLiveData booksLiveData = new FirebaseQueryLiveData(getBooksQuery());
```

Somehow when Users updates, I need to get the data of Books as well and then merge them, but I also need this to happen if Books updates and then get the data of Users and merge them.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Note/Observation**
Okay, so I'm not completely ruling out a MediatorLiveData object.  Certainly it allows me the listening of two different LiveData objects within the same method, however, I don't want to merge the two of them directly because I need to act on each liveData object individually.  So as an example: usersLiveData fires because we create or modify a user, then I need to query books, get the results and merge users and books etc.

Below is my MediatorLiveData as it currently stands:

```
//MediatorLiveData merge two LiveData QuerySnapshot streams
private MediatorLiveData<QuerySnapshot> usersBooksLiveDataMerger() {
    final MediatorLiveData<QuerySnapshot> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(usersLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(querySnapshot);
        }
    });
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(booksLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(querySnapshot);
        }
    });
    return mediatorLiveData;
}
```

Right now it's returning null results of the other LiveData source.  Instead I need to query then merge.  Any ideas on how to do this?  There isn't much out there on this very thing.

I tried putting a query inside a Function that is called using a Transformations.map() but because of it be an asynchronous call, the return statement is being called before the query finishes.

Here's my attempt at the Function:

```
    private class ListenUsersGetBooks implements Function<QuerySnapshot, LinkedHashMap<User, List<Book>>> {

        @Override
        public LinkedHashMap<User, List<Book>> apply(final QuerySnapshot input) {
            userBookList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            getBooksQuery().get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    List<User> users = input.toObjects(User.class);
                    List<Book> books = task.getResult().toObjects(Book.class);
                    Log.d(TAG, "USERLIST! " + users);
                    Log.d(TAG, "BOOKLIST! " + books);
                    for (User user : users) {
                        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Book book : books) {
                            if (user.getUserID().equals(book.getUserID())
                                    && book.getBookAssigned()) {
                                bookList.add(book);
                            }
                            else if (user.getAllBookID().equals(book.getBookID())) {
                                bookList.add(book);
                            }
                        }
                        userBookList.put(user, bookList);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"OBSERVE userBookList: " + userBookList);
                }
            });
            return userBookList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple version of what you could do, I hope it makes sense.

You're close with the `MediatorLiveData`.  Instead of `MediatorLiveData<QuerySnapshot>` you probably want to use a custom object like this:

```
class MyResult {

  public QuerySnapshot usersSnapshot;
  public QuerySnapshot booksSnapshot;

  public MyResult() {}

  boolean isComplete() {
    return (usersSnapshot != null && booksSnapshot != null);
  }
}
```

Then in your observers, do something like this:

```
private MediatorLiveData<MyResult> usersBooksLiveDataMerger() {
    final MediatorLiveData<MyResult> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(usersLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            MyResult current = mediatorLiveData.getValue();
            current.usersSnapshot = querySnapshot;
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
        }
    });
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(booksLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            MyResult current = mediatorLiveData.getValue();
            current.booksSnapshot = querySnapshot;
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
        }
    });
    return mediatorLiveData;
}
```

Then when you observe the combined live data:

```
usersBooksLiveDataMerger().observe(new Observer<MyResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable MyResult result) {
        if (result == null || !result.isComplete()) {
          // Ignore, this means only one of the queries has fininshed
          return;
        }

        // If you get to here, you know all the queries are ready!
        // ...
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam!  I really appreciate the guidance.  I tried your code sample, but I'm getting an incompatible types error with this:
MyResult current = mediatorLiveData.getValue();  We are setting the QuerySnapshot to Class MyResult and android isn't liking that.

Comment: You're right: it should me a MediatorLiveData<MyResult>

Comment: Also I did not mean for this code to be copy-paste ready: make sure to check for `null` when appropriate!

Comment: Of course.  Thanks for the fix.  I'm tweaking from your starting point.   At the moment I'm not getting any results in the observer.  I'm gonna see if I can identify where things are going wrong.

Comment: Okay, so here's the issue I'm running into with this.  The querySnapshots are firing as they are supposed to.  However, the problem is that I need the results of both queries even if just one fires.  The way your sample is setup, I'll never get the entire results because  only one of them most likely fires.  I may edit/add a user, but when that happens I still need to query the books.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I feel like I need to somehow trigger the other query when one fires THEN merge them together using the MediatorLiveData.

Comment: Okay, I went back and read the LiveData docs again.  I think I understand  that MediatorLiveData should work for this purpose.  Since LiveData will update itself when the lifecycle becomes active or after a state change as explained in the docs.  So, I just need to figure out why I'm not getting the data to the observer

Comment: Yes exactly.  The data starts flowing when there is an active observer.  Adding an observer to the mediator also activates the "child" sources.

Comment: Even though I had to make some adjustments to your answer Sam you helped me narrow down my issue, so I'll make yours as THE answer.  Thanks again @Sam Stern!

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it.  We were declaring a new MyResult object in each mediatorLiveData.addSource() method.  Which meant that we were getting a new object for each QuerySnapshot so we would never get them to merge with each other.

Here's the update to MediatorLiveData:

```
    private MediatorLiveData<MyResult> usersBooksLiveDataMerger() {
        final MediatorLiveData<MyResult> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        final MyResult current = new MyResult();
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(usersLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                current.setUsersSnapshot(querySnapshot);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
            }
        });
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(booksLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                current.setBooksSnapshot(querySnapshot);
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
            }
        });
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }
```

Now I'm getting users and books in the observer in Activity!  Now the only thing I need to do is transform (merge the data) into a LinkedHashMap, but I think I got that figured out.  Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 0):

So this is where I am with your suggestions Sam.

I added getter and setter methods to the MyResult class as it wasn't giving me access to the member variables in the observer otherwise:

```
    public class MyResult {

        QuerySnapshot usersSnapshot;
        QuerySnapshot booksSnapshot;

        //default constructor
        public MyResult() {
        }

        public QuerySnapshot getUsersSnapshot() {
            return usersSnapshot;
        }

        public void setUsersSnapshot(QuerySnapshot usersSnapshot) {
            this.usersSnapshot = usersSnapshot;
        }

        public QuerySnapshot getBooksSnapshot() {
            return booksSnapshot;
        }

        public void setBooksSnapshot(QuerySnapshot booksSnapshot) {
            this.booksSnapshot = booksSnapshot;
        }

        public boolean isComplete() {
            return (usersSnapshot != null && booksSnapshot != null);
        }
    }
```

Here's the MediatorLiveData and get method.  I changed the MyResult class initialization to = new MyResult(); thinking there was an issue with using mediatorLiveData.getValue(); as the initialization and get method.

```
private MediatorLiveData<MyResult> usersBooksLiveDataMerger() {
    final MediatorLiveData<MyResult> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(usersLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            MyResult current = new MyResult();
            current.setUsersSnapshot(querySnapshot);
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
        }
    });
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(booksLiveData, new Observer<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            MyResult current = new MyResult();
            current.setBooksSnapshot(querySnapshot);
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(current);
        }
    });
    return mediatorLiveData;
}

public MediatorLiveData<MyResult> getUsersBooksLiveDataMerger() {
    return usersBooksLiveDataMerger();
}
```

And finally the observer:

```
    mainViewModel.getUsersBooksLiveDataMerger().observe(this, new Observer<MainViewModel.MyResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable MainViewModel.MyResult myResult) {
                if (myResult == null || !myResult.isComplete()) {
                    // Ignore, this means only one of the queries has fininshed
                    Log.d(TAG, "OBSERVE BLAH!!!!");
                    return;
                }

                // If you get to here, you know all the queries are ready!
                // ...
                List<Book> books;
                List<User> users;
                books = myResult.getBooksSnapshot().toObjects(Book.class);
                users = myResult.getUsersSnapshot().toObjects(User.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "OBSERVE MERGE users: " + users);
                Log.d(TAG, "OBSERVE MERGE books: " + books);
            }
        });
```

Please note: I did do a null check in the mediatorLiveData, just took it out for testing purposes.

Somehow I need to trigger my books query if just my users is triggered AND I need to trigger my users query if just my books is triggered...I feel like there is a step before the MediatorLiveData that needs to happen so we can make sure one liveData triggers the other query.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify the usage by using my **LiveDataZipExtensions** https://gist.github.com/Benjiko99/d2e5406aab0a4a775ea747956ae16624

With them, you don't have to create an object to hold your combined result.

**Example usage**

```
val firstNameLD = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "John" }
val lastNameLD = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "Smith" }

// The map function will get called once all zipped LiveData are present
val fullNameLD = zip(firstNameLD, lastNameLD).map { (firstName, lastName) ->
    "$firstName $lastName"
}
```